# Modeling binary outcomes - inaccurate model when using logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, binomial-distribution, binary-data, smoothing

I am trying to model the probability of a binary outcome with the independent variable being an hour variable. I understand that linear regression is not the correct method for this type of task (I wont go into my simplified understanding of why, if someone wants to add a succinct explanation I'm all for it).  The problem I am running into is that logistic regression does not seem to accurately capture the trend in my data, which is inverse parabolic (low probability early, increasing to a peak at the middle of day and decreasing at the end).  My test data is as follows, I just supplied the `ggplot` and `stat_smooth()` curve I am looking at vs. the model itself:

```
testset <- data.frame(
             hour=c(rep(100,100),rep(200,100),rep(300,100),rep(400,100),rep(500,100)),  
             data=c(rbinom(100,1,.25),rbinom(100,1,.3),rbinom(100,1,.5),
                      rbinom(100,1,.25),rbinom(100,1,.1)))

ggplot(data=testset,aes(hour,data))+stat_smooth(method=glm,family=binomial)
```

Notice that is I allow the stat_smooth function to default to a fitting/smoothing method (loess in this case), the representation is closer to the actual data.  I know I am missing something terribly simple, or misunderstanding something in a silly way, but that is why I am asking the question, search didn't help.

```
ggplot(data=testset,aes(hour,data))+stat_smooth()
```

Comment: correction:  I guess I do know one reason not to use a linear model, because outcomes beyond the bounds of a binary variable become possible.  Maybe that is the only reason?

Comment: We need to know what logit model you fitted. Have you included both hour and hour^2? Then the non-linearity should be captured.

Comment: I think it would have been defaulting to y~x (data~hour), but even when I use ggplot(data=testset,aes(hour,data))+geom_smooth(formula=y~x+x^2,method=glm,family=binomial) I still can't capture the non-linearity

Comment: capturing non-linearity in regression models fairly broad topic. You could (1) use polynomials as suggested. X^2 will not be sufficient. (2) Bin data into 5-10 groups to create categorical variable (3) restricted regression splines (4) GAM models (5) plus few more. each has strengths and limitations.

Comment: I would not recommend binning into groups.  Group boundaries are arbitrary and the resulting predicted values will have higher mean squared error due to taking more degrees of freedom while having worse fit (it assumes piecewise flatness).

Comment: Although this is off-topic the OP problem may be that x^2 in an R formula does not do what he expects, it should be I(x^2)